# What happens if I have an acid/base equillibrium and remove hydronium ions until there is 50/50 of acid and conjugate base?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

Suppose I had an acid HA, and it reaches equilibrium in water. Then I remove the hydronium ions. I don't know how I would do this, maybe adding some hydroxide ions. My question is can I do this and will I be able to eventually create a 50/50 mixture of acid and conjugate base? Is this a very good buffer?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎

Comment: The quick answer is that it depends what 'A' is.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just remove hydronium ions because the solution needs to remain electrically neutral.

You can't just add hydroxide ions, but you could add sodium hydroxide until the HA/A- ratio was 50/50.

> Is this a very good buffer?

It is the optimum ratio of HA and A- for buffering.